# Page with German text (django/python)

Tags: python, django, decode, encode, utf8-decode

I have a simple HTML page providing information to users in German language which contains characters like `ä`, `ü`, `ö` etc.

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 795: invalid start byte
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Example:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<div class="page">
<div class="content wide">
    <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="txt">
        Some text in German containing ä, ö, ü, ß ...
        </div>
</div> <!-- end content -->
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is for instance for the Impressum page one places in the footer.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code snippet, please? Is the html page utf-8?

Comment: Django and Python handle German characters perfectly well; there's no way of knowing what's going wrong in your case without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: The page seems to be "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text" as soon as there is an ä, ö or ü character somewhere in the text.

Comment: You need to encode the template as UTF-8. Tell your editor to save it as UTF-8.

Comment: Isn't switching to UTF-8 going to replace those characters with codes which become unreadable in the editor? Or am I getting this wrong? I'd still like to be able to read the text in the template.